# Solve issue when http won't change to https

Tags: http, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have installed an SSL-certificate for my website but it is not working for some pages. I went inside of the Google Chrome Console option and found this error message:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.feelhome.se/produkt/blackgrey-feather/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure font
>   'http://www.feelhome.se/wp-content/plugins/ajax-search-pro/css/fonts/icons/icons.woff'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I went inside of the "insecure font" but there is not "http" URL there that I can change to remove this error message. How can I remove this error message that appears?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the reference to the font in your CSS file so that it uses a https:// URL.

All external resources (css, javascript, images, etc) imported into the page need to either be relative URL so that they automatically use the same protocol, or you need to explicitly use https:// in their URL.

Comment: Relative means without starting `http://www.feelhome.se`. Just remove it and the link is relative.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to get chrome to tell you where the URLs are, you'll just have to try and find them on your own probably.  The error you quoted mentions *ajax-search-pro* so I checked those stylesheets and found the reference in [style.instances.css](https://www.feelhome.se/wp-content/plugins/ajax-search-pro/css/style.instances.css)

Comment: @Robin Lundgren: Exactly. If someone access the page via http it loads the icon via http. If someone access it via https it loads the file through https, too.

Comment: @Robin Lundgren: You can remove all links to it. Edit your post and remove it. And also delete the comment you posted the image. If the image itself can be deleted - I don't know.

Comment: @Robert Thank you, I have removed those in the OP. About the question earlier, how can I fix this error message: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.feelhome.se/produkt/canvastavla-efter-eget-motiv/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700,600italic,600,400italic,300italic,300,200italic,200'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

Comment: Read the answer by kicken - it is everything in it you need.